# PHP MySQL data insertion in database no error is showing

Tags: php, mysql, blob

No error is showing and also code is not working. Nothing happens to database too.  When I open my page insert.php and fill out the details it just reset the form.

//insert.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert Record</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><p />
        Roll No.: <input type="text" name="rollno"><br><p />
        Duration: <input type="text" name="duration"><br><p />
        Course: <input type="text" name="course"><br><p />
        Date of Birth: <input type="text" name="dob"><br><p />
        Photo: <input type="file" name="image"><br><p />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    error_reporting(0);


    //connection
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "vision";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
     if (!isset($file))
         {echo "Please Select an Image";}
        else
        { 
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $rollno = $_POST["rollno"];
            $duration = $_POST["duration"];
            $dob = $_POST["dob"];
            $course = $_POST["course"];
            $image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
            //$image_name= addslashes($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $image_size=  getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    //inserting data

            if($image_size==FALSE)
                {echo "That's not an Image";}
            else
            {       
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO record(rollno,name,duration,dob,course,image)VALUES('$rollno','$name','$duration','$dob','$course','$image')");

                if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE)
                {
                    echo "<br>Input data is succeed";
                } 
                else
                {
                    echo "<br>Input data is fail";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: becoz you put error_reporting(0); change into error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: btw: putting images into db is bad idea

Comment: write enctype="multipart/form-data" in form open tag as you are uploading images/files

Comment: How do you develop your PHP? I recommend an IDE (I use NetBeans, but use whatever you want, so long as you use an IDE and not an editor). Set a breakpint, step through your code a line at a time, examine variables & you will soon discover your problems. That's your fishing lesson ;-)

Comment: after adding error_reporting(E_ALL); it is showing be following error || Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\VisionBackEnd\insert.php on line 34

Comment: have you write enctype="multipart/form-data" ?? 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: *At least you haven't got `MySQL` and `MySQLi` mixed up..*

Comment: @AnandPatel Sir I already added || enctype="multipart/form-data || . when i added error_reporting(E_ALL); instead of error_reporting(0); it is showing Undefined Index: image Error.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code. Don't put it live, your database may not last long!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because nothing will be displayed when no image exists and there never will be an image. When you want to POST an image you need to add the `enctype` tag `multipart/form-data`.

Change

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

To

```
<form action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

And if you add an image to your form it will reach the `$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INS....` line.

Comment: and the `error_reporting(0);`..

Comment: He already did according to the comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

use :-

```
<form action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: No, according to PHP the procedural style is `mysqli_query ($conn , $query) `

Comment: okey, i have corrected that one :-)  thanks